# How to run react-native application in android which is cloned from a github repository?

Tags: android, react-native, github

I was working on a local project from scratch which was not on github and it was running successfully. But when i clone a project from github and try to run on android, mostly ***(not every application cloned from github gives me this error but few big application gives)*** it gives me error like

Command That I run:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Error that I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have to download the gradle files first before running it. Follow the steps and it will definitely run.

- Step 1: Clone the project from github repo.
- Step 2: Open it in any
  code editor (I prefer VS code).
- Step 3: Install node_modules by
  running `npm install` command in terminal.
- Step 4: Open android
  studio and open the **react-native-app/android folder** inside it.

**Note: Android Studio will automatically start downloading the gradle and build it, which you can see in bottom part of android studio.**

- Step 5: After gradle files are downloaded and build successfully, go back to the code editor and try to run your app again using

  `npx react-native run-android`

**Note: If it shows the same error restart your code editor or laptop and it will work like a charm.**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have configure the environment of react native in your machine(desktop/laptop).

follow the link for environment Setup:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup
after that follow below steps:

1. Clone the project from `github`.
2. cd `projectName`
3. `npm` install
4. `npx` react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

Clone the project and Open that folder

--> npm install

--> cd ios -> pod install

--> gradle wrapper

--> npx react-native run-android